# span vertical align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem aligning text vertically at the top of the span.

`vertical-align: top`; `text-top` etc...do not work and it is span which is `display: inline-block`.

Please have a look at the code and a snapshot of the output.

The output looks more like center aligned and not top aligned.

Would be greatful if someone could help.

```
<span id="myspan" contenteditable="true" style="font-size:30px;" 
                                                        class="textImage" >
     This is text inside the span
</span>
<button id="mybutton" type="button">Increase Font</button>
```

css:

```
  .textImage
{
    border: solid 4px #000000;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 240px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}​
```

Javascript:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(event) {
    document.getElementById("myspan").style.fontSize = 
                  (parseInt(document.getElementById("myspan").style.fontSize, 10)
                                                    + parseInt(4, 10)) + 'px';
});​
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the CSS line-height property value?

Comment: you can still see the margin between the tallest element and the top of the span..I want the tallest element to be at the top with no gap at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most fonts take up more height for each character than that visibly taken by say the character T. You'll be able to see this clearly if you select some text. The height of the selection should give you an idea about the actual height of each character in the font you've used. If the selection highlight is seen as touching the inside top of your span, that means the text is indeed top aligned. If you notice any gap between the top of the selection and the inner top of your span, you should be able to correct that by removing any `padding-top` given to the span.

Comment: I was all the while thinking that something is wrong with the padding-top or so..but selecting the font shows indeed that there is no gap..for my application it is not very critical to avoid this though would have been good. I think I will live with the issue. Nevertheless I will accept your answer ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `vertical-align` property applies to the entire block, not the text within it.  I don't know of any way to get a browser to treat a letterform as anything other than part of the font as a whole, as regards its height.

You could try something like [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com) (or just do what it does) to align your characters.

If you just want the *tallest* character at the top of the box, you can reduce the `line-height` setting. Exactly how much depends on the font, but something around `0.9em` should get you close.

Comment: that you so much for leading to the nice "js". However, the solution will be like hitting a neddle with a hammer in my case as it is not very critical problem..I guess will live with it. Is it possible to accept 2 answers?

Comment: Don't worry about it - techfoobar provided some clearer information about font spacing anyway :-)